# Different userId get same document with server publish this.userId

Tags: meteor

With autopublish package is removed, While this Meteor code is running, a different userId has been confirmed on 2 different browsers consoles `Meteor.userId();`
But when a string is typed in the inputText of one of them, and a `collection.insert` is done, the other shows the same string.
I thought that `this.userId` was good enough for the server to publish only the documents that belongs to each of the different clients simultaneously.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?  Thanks

Server

```
Meteor.publish('displayCol', function () {
  return DisplayCol.find({userId: this.userId});
});
DisplayCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
});
```

Client

```
Template.index.helpers({
  taskInputs: function () {
    var ready = Meteor.subscribe('displayCol').ready();
    var data = DisplayCol.find({});
    return {items: data, ready: ready};
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have autopublish still installed? If so, both clients will get everything automatically. Remove it with 'meteor remove autopublish' 
You can also add the {userId: Meteor.userId()} condition on the client side.

Comment: does that mean the use of this.userId on the server is useless?

Comment: Absolutely not. The autopublish package is only meant to be used for rapid prototyping without having to worry about data security. It seems you are past that phase, so it's time to remove it from your project.